# How to stop row ID from getting bigger

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this code, which parses JSON and is beeing run every **5 MINS** via `php file.php` command.

```
foreach($data->chatters->staff as $viewers)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO viewers (user,points)
            VALUES('$viewers','10')
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            points = points+5";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    //echo "Staff: Done";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}
```

For some reason, every cycle it increases the ID count. 
Now my database looks like this:

```
id user points
1 uname1 123
2 uname2 123
18 uname3 123
256 uname4 123
```

And the ID value just keeps increasing. What am i missing?

THanks.

Comment: Run manually and check how it's increased.

Comment: Where came your `id` column?

Comment: should not "user" be your primary key here ?

Comment: In your code you have `user,points` the table is `id,name`.Question doesnt make sense

Comment: Dude you need to set `auto increament` and `PRIMARY KEY` on `id` field. also `Truncate your table`

Comment: Sorry, i thought ill make it clearer, but apparently i did it wrong. Updated the database "view".

Comment: ID is auto increment and primary

Comment: It inserts first, but a record is duplicated - so a value for `id` has been "wasted" (this is on purpose and has to do with handling concurrency). Every time you "hit" a unique constraint, MySQL will spend 1 value for `auto_increment`, it doesn't matter if you have `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` there. Basically, this is a completely normal behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before explaining: what you are experiencing is **normal**.

The `id` number gets generated for every `INSERT` query. It's an atomic operation, plus the feature is designed to work in concurrent environment (many people hitting one db with lots of requests).

In order to be able to concurrently serve, MySQL isolates transactions from each other and each transaction lives it its own "bubble". That means, every time an insert happens and auto_increment is generated, it **can't produce the same value for different queries**.

The only way for this to work is for MySQL to always increase the number and never re-use it. That's the only possible solution and the fastest one as well.

What does this mean - it means that every time you hit a unique constraint in your query, a value that was generated for `auto_increment` will be "wasted", insert won't happen and instead the `UPDATE` part gets executed.

You can't fix it, you can just break it. Leave it as it is, you've done it right.

The job of `auto_increment` is only to provide unique numbers. If they got spent somehow (by a failed insert) then that's fine and not something you need to worry about.

Comment: Thank you, was worndering, since i thought it might hit limit if ill keep cycling it like that.

Comment: The limit is pretty high.. around 4.2 billion. If you need more, use `bigint` so you won't exhaust the limit for next few thousand years :)

Answer (score 0):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will create a new row each time you 'update' the row.

If you don't want it to be like that, you'll have to make two queries : one for the `INSERT` query, another one for the `UPDATE`query.

Comment: This is completely false... I'm not downvoting, but you missed the whole point and provided inaccurate explanation. Also, your advice on how to remedy this is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the "downvote-free" comment. Your answer explains it way better than mine. But, as I think he wants to keep the ids the same for every user, how is the second part of my answer wrong ?

Comment: Well, if you split stuff into two queries - what do you get that's not being covered with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`? You have to insert in order to know there's a duplicate. You can't query first, check if you got a row or not because that's not concurrency-safe.. so that part is slightly wrong, unless you had something else in mind that I missed :)

Comment: What I understood is : he wants to create an new row, with an automatic id, and then be able to update the row with the new note, without updating the id. So, creating the row is quite simple, and then a second query like `UPDATE viewers SET score = score+5 WHERE user = :username:s` will only update the score, not the id.

Comment: But he's not updating the `id`, in any case. The `id` gets spent for a failed `INSERT` query. It would always happen, there's a `unique` constraint somewhere, probably on `users` column. So whatever happens, if you try to insert the same user, you will spend this `id` that got generated anyway. There's no way of stopping this and being safe from concurrency.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I totally misunderstood. Thanks for the explanations.